# how to compile js to es5 with laravel mix?

Tags: laravel-5, webpack, babeljs, laravel-mix

I have laravel Vue app and it works perfectly with chrome and firefox. but it doesn't work on Edge or IE11 and the console shows error on arrow function!?
How to compile or transpile to es5 with laravel mix and webpack?
could you show the correct configuration for webpack.mix.js?
tnx alot

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE February 2020**

If anyone still need help with this, `mix` already provide a babel compilation to es5:

> A slight variation of mix.scripts() is mix.babel(). Its method
>   signature is identical to scripts; however, the concatenated file will
>   receive Babel compilation, which translates any ES2015 code to vanilla
>   JavaScript that all browsers will understand.

You can use it like this:

```
mix.babel(['public/js/es6file.js'], 'public/js/app.es5.js')
```

[DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#vanilla-js)

Answer (score 2):

In order to compile your es6 code to es5 follow the following steps:

1) install the babel-env preset

```
npm install @babel/preset-env --save
```

And then declare it in your .babelrc in the root directory:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

2) compile your code using

```
npm run dev //for dev environment
```

or

```
npm run prod // for production environment
```

Comment: I've done what you told and now I get an error on "...this"  and generally anywhere with "this" keyword. it is becoming frustrating for me.

Comment: So sorry about that, what error are you getting exactly? And can you show a snippet of the code where the issue occurs in?

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of search, I've found out that this Vuecomponent causes the error "https://github.com/godbasin/vue-select2" how can I compile it to es5.

the edge console error:
`Expected identifier, string or number`

and the corresponding line that it shows is this:

```
setOption(val = []) {
      this.select2.empty();
      this.select2.select2({
----->     ...this.settings,
        data: val
      });
      this.setValue(this.value);
    },
```

sorry for taking your time